# Extract Regex Substring from Pandas column that meets criteria

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Regex Extract all substrings that meet the following criteria:

- first 4 chars are numbers and substring ends with number or
  letter
- 15 or 18 chars long
- If there are 2 substrings that meet the criteria, just return the first one

  ```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(data ={"Messy_IDS":["Looking for ID : 7010M000002N8c5T7A","5634M000002N8c5T7A,7010M000002N8c5T7A","https://website.com/12340000000f5F5"], "Desired_Output":["7010M000002N8c5T7A","5634M000002N8c5T7A","12340000000f5F5"]})
  ```

df1

```
        Messy_IDS                                Desired_Output
   0    Looking for ID : 7010M000002N8c5T7A      7010M000002N8c5T7A
   1    5634M000002N8c5T7A,7010M000002N8c5T7A    5634M000002N8c5T7A
   2    https://website.com/12340000000f5F5      12340000000f5F5
```

Comment: can you share your attempt? and the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with match by regex for first 4 digits and then for `11` or `14` digits or letters:

```
df['new'] = df['Messy_IDS'].str.extract('([0-9]{4}[0-9A-Za-z]{11,14})')
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df['Messy_IDS'].str.extract('(\d{4}\w{11,14})')
```

---

```
print (df)
                               Messy_IDS      Desired_Output  \
0    Looking for ID : 7010M000002N8c5T7A  7010M000002N8c5T7A   
1  5634M000002N8c5T7A,7010M000002N8c5T7A  5634M000002N8c5T7A   
2    https://website.com/12340000000f5F5     12340000000f5F5   

                  new  
0  7010M000002N8c5T7A  
1  5634M000002N8c5T7A  
2     12340000000f5F5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code

```
df1["Messy_IDS"].str.extract("(\d{4}\w+)")
```